# как сделать так что бы таймер не сбрасывался при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript

у меня есть вот такой код, как сделать так что бы таймер продолжал отчет, а не сбрасывался при перезагрузке, за ранее спаибо!

```js
window.onload = function(){ // дожидаемся загрузки страницы
 initializeTimer(); // вызываем функцию инициализации таймера
}


function initializeTimer() {
 seconds = 86400;
 if (seconds > 0) { // проверка - истекла ли дата обратного отсчета
  var minutes = seconds/60; // определяем количество минут до истечения таймера
  var hours = minutes/60; // определяем количество часов до истечения таймера
  minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60; // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе
  hours = Math.floor(hours); // целое количество часов до истечения таймера
  seconds = Math.floor((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60); // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся секунд в текущей минуте
  minutes = Math.floor(minutes); // округляем до целого кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе
  

  setTimePage(hours,minutes,seconds); // выставляем начальные значения таймера
  
  function secOut() {
    localStorage.setItem("a",seconds);
    if (seconds == 0) { // если секунду закончились то
     if (minutes == 0) { // если минуты закончились то
      if (hours == 0) { // если часы закончились то
       showMessage(timerId); // выводим сообщение об окончании отсчета
      }
      else {
       hours--; // уменьшаем кол-во часов
       minutes = 59; // обновляем минуты 
       seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
      }
     }
     else {
      minutes--; // уменьшаем кол-во минут
      seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
     }
    }
    else {
     seconds--; // уменьшаем кол-во секунд
    }
   



    setTimePage(hours,minutes,seconds); // обновляем значения таймера на странице
  

  }
  timerId = setInterval(secOut, 1000) // устанавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
 }
 else {
  alert("Установленная дата уже прошла");
 }
}

function setTimePage(h,m,s) { // функция выставления таймера на странице
 var element = document.getElementById("timer"); // находим элемент с id = timer
 element.innerHTML = "Часы: "+h+" Минуты: "+m+" Секунды:"+s; // выставляем новые значения таймеру на странице
}

function showMessage(timerId) { // функция, вызываемая по истечению времени
 alert("Время истекло!");
 clearInterval(timerId); // останавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
}
```

Comment: веротяно вот так `seconds = +localStorage.getItem("a") || 86400`

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() { // дожидаемся загрузки страницы
  initializeTimer(); // вызываем функцию инициализации таймера
}


function initializeTimer() {
  seconds = localStorage.getItem('sec') || 86400;
  if (seconds > 0) { // проверка - истекла ли дата обратного отсчета
    var minutes = seconds / 60; // определяем количество минут до истечения таймера
    var hours = minutes / 60; // определяем количество часов до истечения таймера
    minutes = localStorage.getItem('min') || (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60; // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе
    hours = localStorage.getItem('hours') || Math.floor(hours); // целое количество часов до истечения таймера
    seconds = localStorage.getItem('sec') || Math.floor((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) *
      60); // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся секунд в текущей минуте
    minutes = Math.floor(minutes); // округляем до целого кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе


    setTimePage(hours, minutes, seconds); // выставляем начальные значения таймера

    function secOut() {
      localStorage.setItem("sec", seconds);
      localStorage.setItem("min", minutes);
      localStorage.setItem("hours", hours);
      if (seconds == 0) { // если секунду закончились то
        if (minutes == 0) { // если минуты закончились то
          if (hours == 0) { // если часы закончились то
            showMessage(timerId); // выводим сообщение об окончании отсчета
          } else {
            hours--; // уменьшаем кол-во часов
            minutes = 59; // обновляем минуты 
            seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
          }
        } else {
          minutes--; // уменьшаем кол-во минут
          seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
        }
      } else {
        seconds--; // уменьшаем кол-во секунд
      }

      setTimePage(hours, minutes, seconds); // обновляем значения таймера на странице

    }
    timerId = setInterval(secOut, 1000) // устанавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
  } else {
    alert("Установленная дата уже прошла");
  }
}

function setTimePage(h, m, s) { // функция выставления таймера на странице
  var element = document.getElementById("timer"); // находим элемент с id = timer
  element.innerHTML = "Часы: " + h + " Минуты: " + m + " Секунды:" + s; // выставляем новые значения таймеру на странице
}

function showMessage(timerId) { // функция, вызываемая по истечению времени
  alert("Время истекло!");
  clearInterval(timerId); // останавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'></div>
```

Здесь не сработает, попробуйте запустить в своём файле. Добавил работу с `localstorage`

Comment: Спасибо большое добрый человек!